# Combinatorics question from exam - possibly pigeonhole question.

Tags: combinatorics

My question is as follows:

A student is preparing for an exam for 13 days. He studies at least for 1 hour every day, and overall he studied no more than 20 hours (over the span of all 13 days that is).

Show that there is a sequence of days (consecutive days, one after another) where overall he studied for 4 hours exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is *one* possible solution:

General idea: we prove there must be enough days with 1 or 2 hours to find the 4 hours. For this we can look at sequences of 4 consecutive days (actually we only need to consider the sequences 1-4, 5-8,9-12,13).

There is a sequence of 4 consecutive days on which the student worked at most 6 hours (otherwise he would work at least 7+7+7+1=22hours; this is a pigeonhole argument of a sort).

- If these 4 days (with at most 6-hour) he worked at most 2 hours a day, 
  then you can find a 4-hour sequence (check all possibilities: either it contains two 2, or one 2 with two 1, or it contains four 1).
- Otherwise the student worked three hours some day and 1 hour every other day
  -> 3+1 gives 4-hour

Comment: Hi, thanks Joseph. I have just one thing that is not clear to me. I understood what you wrote and I agree it shows what we wanted, but why did they say $13$ days then? it was redundant. the question wouldn't have changed if they said $12$ days. you still could have divided to days $1-4,5-8,9-12$ and did the exact same thing.

Comment: I agree. But there is no particular reason for the constraints of an exercise to be "tight". However, an implicit (missing) assumption is that each day, only full hours are worked (but this is not related to the 12 vs 13 days).

Comment: Yes there is a reason for them to be tight. So far I haven't seen one question (at least in the university im studying at) where the constraints aren't tight. They are not lenient in that sense. They give you exactly the amount of information you need. No more, no less.